# How to claim living / transport / visa expenditure in Income tax for working in abroad while being a Indian Resident working for that financial year

Tags: income-tax, india, non-resident, dtaa, nigeria

I was working in India till oct 2014, and have paid all my taxes from April 2014 till Nov 2014 as per my employment in India, 
after that I moved to abroad in Nov 2014 for my employment.
I have spent for me and my family visa and air fare.
I am getting  45% in local currency and 55% as USD in  my NRE account at India (by my choice of payment mode).

Till march 2015 I received my local salary for all 5 month, while only 2 month for my USD part.

My employer is deducting 26.25% tax on my local salary as “PAYE” tag in my pay slip.
I am not getting any tax paid statement.
I am paying for my accommodation and transportation.
I want to know,

1. Do I have to pay any tax in India for this duration.
2. If  I have to pay any tax in India ,can I claim my expenditure for my visa / air fare / accommodation / school fees of my child etc?
3. How much tax I have to pay is it the amount deposited in my account till  31 March 2015. (ie same as in India).
4. How to take Local currency into consideration ( Local Currency to USD and back to INR).
5. If any tax liability on USD amount how should I calculate based on amount deposite in my account or base price of conversion
6. How much tax I have to pay in India as already 26.25% for local salary tax has been deducted by my employer

Please suggest

Comment: Welcome to [Money.SE].  Please add a tag to your question indicating what country you're currently living in.

Answer (score 1):

For the financial year 1 April 2014 to 31 March 2015, you are deemed "Resident" for tax purposes. Hence you have pay tax on your Global Income.

> Do I have to pay any tax in India for this duration.

Yes. You need to consider the local salary, the amount deposited into India as well.

> If I have to pay any tax in India ,can I claim my expenditure for my visa / air fare / accommodation / school fees of my child etc?

No

> How much tax I have to pay is it the amount deposited in my account till 31 March 2015. (ie same as in India).

It would be on the complete salary, local plus what you are supposed to get in India.

> How to take Local currency into consideration ( Local Currency to USD and back to INR).

Yes

> If any tax liability on USD amount how should I calculate based on amount deposite in my account or base price of conversion

On what gets credited in INR

> How much tax I have to pay in India as already 26.25% for local salary tax has been deducted by my employer

As per your tax bracket.

India and Nigeria don't currently have a [DTAA](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/international-taxation/dtaa.aspx) . There was one previously but that's no longer valid. A new one is being negotiated. Hence you are out of luck. If there was DTAA in place, you could have claimed relief to the extent of taxes paid in Nigeria.